Unable to Crack WordPress PHPass Hash with John the Ripper
I am trying to crack a WordPress password hash using John the Ripper but haven't had any success so far. Here's the information about my setup and what I've tried:
Hash Format: PHPass ($P$BFLCjvS3t9kla1FH6.gb5DtJMQgjRa1)
Command Used:
john --format=phpass --wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt hash.txt
Wordlist: Using the default rockyou.txt provided in Kali Linux.
Result: John runs through the wordlist but doesn't crack the password. Running john --show hash.txt shows 0 password hashes cracked.
I've verified that the hash is correctly formatted and the file only contains the hash.
Questions:
Is there something wrong with my setup or approach?
Are there any advanced John the Ripper rules or configurations I should try for PHPass hashes?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Try generating a PHPass hash which you know should be found with this dictionary attack and try again. If it doesn't find it, there must be something wrong with your setup, otherwise the hash above just isn't going to be solved with this dictionary attack. You could try brute force, but with this hash that's going to be difficult unless it's a guessable hash format.

I am gonna try this, thanks @SimonGoater
